# Optimizar código de archivo SVG para la web

Tags: html, svg, optimizar, illustrator

Vectoricé una imagen en Illustrator y la estoy exportando como .SVG, hasta aquí todo bien. El problema es que el código me queda muy extenso, tiene mas de doce mil lineas...Estuve leyendo otras respuestas y buscando en internet, pero no logro sintetizar el código. Tengo cada imagen con su respectivo ID en capas.

Alguna sugerencia de como podría hacer que el código sea más pequeño y/o optimizado?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Deja vu?  Debes buscar por "simplify path ilustrator". Tu estabas haciendo un mapa según recuerdo, si tienes mucho detalle en los países eso te origina este problema. No necesitas tanto detalle si no es una aplicación geográfica

Comment: jajaja Ay si, soy yo! y vos me re ayudaste!!! mil gracias me sirvió, a medida que avanzo me surgen estas dudas, no sabía lo de "simplify path ilustrator" voy a investigar eso entonces, justamente tengo muchas etiquetas path, demasiadas y eso es lo que origina un código tan extenso!